# Angular 6 AngularFireAuth check if user is logged in before page rendered

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have set up a new angular 6 project with Firebase auth and Cloud Fire Store. There is a login page where you can login via google and the user data is saved in Firestore (code below). My only issue is how I can check if the user is already logged in, is there any best practice?

At the moment im fetching the user data async, but then the navigation is flickering. For one second there is the login button, then it switches to the logout button. Is there good way to check the login state before it renders the page?
[image]
[image: one second later]

> User.ts

```js
export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
}
```

> auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore, private router: Router) {
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        switchMap(user => {
          if (user) {
            return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
          } else {
            return of(null);
          }
        }))
  }

  public googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }

  public signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential) => {
        this.updateUserData(credential.user)
      })
  }

  private updateUserData(user) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);
    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email
    }
    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true })
  }

}
```

> navigation.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../core/auth.service';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
```

}

> auth.service.ts

```html
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async; then loggedIn else loggedOut"></div>
                    
<ng-template #loggedOut>
    <li  class="nav-item d-none d-md-inline-block pl-2 pr-0">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary u-btn-primary u-btn-pill transition-3d-hover" href="/login">
            Login
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #loggedIn>
    <li  class="nav-item d-none d-md-inline-block pl-2 pr-0">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary u-btn-primary u-btn-pill transition-3d-hover" (click)="auth.signOut()">
            Logout
        </a>
    </li>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 8):

You probably figured this out a long time ago but someone else might wonder. I chose to do a check against the authState of angularFireAuth. If it's null, then you're logged out. Then You can use route guards as explained in [Ryan Chenkie's Medium article](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)

```
@Injectable()
export class FirebaseAuthService {
private authState: Observable<firebase.User>
private currentUser: firebase.User = null;

constructor(
  public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  private http: HttpClient,
  private localStorage: LocalStorageService,
  private router: Router,
  private snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  this.authState = this.afAuth.authState;

this.authState.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.currentUser = user;
    this.localStorage.storeSimple('userData', user)
    this.openSnackBar('Successfully authenticated');
    console.log('AUTHSTATE USER', user)
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  } else {
    console.log('AUTHSTATE USER EMPTY', user)
    this.currentUser = null;
  }
},
  err => {
    this.openSnackBar(`${err.status} ${err.statusText} (${err.error.message})`, 'Please try again')
  });
 }

 isAuthenticated(): boolean {
   return this.authState !== null;
 }

 loginEmail(email, password, route) {
   this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => {
   let errorCode = error.code;
   let errorMessage = error.message;
   this.openSnackBar(error, 'OK')
 });
}

logout() {
  this.afAuth.auth.signOut()
  .then(response => this.openSnackBar('Signed out'))
  .catch(error => this.openSnackBar('Error signing out: ' + error));
}

...
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution worked for me, can I ask, in the main component how can you get the user ID?

Comment: in the service above i have a function that returns this.currentuser, so in my component, i inject the authentication service and have access to the currentUser variable

Comment: I've tried many times but if I call the currentUser in my main component it returns `null`, please if you can check my answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/q/54961071/10158519]

Comment: alessandro maybe you have several instances of the login service running ?

Comment: Note that just because authState is not null, doesn't mean you're "logged in" in all scenarios. It means your identity is authenticated, for ex. with google login, then google authenticates that you are who you say you are. For your application you might add extra authentication, such as "is this google user allowed to view this data ?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use can activate routes concept present in routing module of angular..... In this concept it just call the injectable service every time when ever the routing or navigation of the page happen.... There you can also check whether the user have permission to view the page or not

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate use this URL as the reference of it..... I just simple .... You need to add &#39;canActivate&#39; array in your routing array in every object, In array of &#39;&#39;canActivate&quot; there will be one or more injectable class. That class can be used for checking whether the user is login or not....

Comment: How can I read the value in the navigation template?
Is there a demo project  where its used like that? Somewhere I need to decide to show the login or logout button...
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: https://alligator.io/angular/route-guards/ use this example to do. It's a routing guard example. There is a method in injectable class 'canActivate' method with 2 parameters. On those parameters all the information was present about your routing in these 2 parameters

Comment: But this would restrict access to the whole page, but I want to change only a button.

Comment: I am also searching about a solution for this.. until the observable gets some value (since is null from the start and then gets the current user value) the button in which u have some conditional logic with async pipe needs some time to decide if it gets rendered or not. Did you solve it after all this time?